# What's the biblical source that showering makes one impure?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

It's "Verachatz Besaro BaMayim VeTamei Ad Haarev" :)

But seriously, are questions looking for "sources" with just a question of where to find something on topic?

We've had quite a few questions like this:

- [Zohar and Sholom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54020/zohar-and-sholom)
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55132/giving-of-ourselves-is-greater-than-giving-charity
- [The Sifra on peace](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55092/the-sifra-on-peace)
- [The chachamim on peace](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54032/the-chachamim-on-peace)

Should we close them?

It seems a lot like the "guessing game" questions. If you don't give me tips on where to find it, or the reason why it's interesting (so that I can look up your sources), I can only do the same thing you can, that's right, Google.

Comment: The four questions you link to and others like them are very distasteful to me because they include no motivation (explanation of why the asker asked them). But I don't think you're right that all one can do is Google. These may be things that Google can't find as are, but that someone who knows what alternative wording to search for can thereby find, or that someone may happens to know the answer to without searching.

Comment: It's problematic to include a verbatim quotation from a secondary source (which is the basis for most or all of these questions) without citing that source. That, by itself, is generally enough for a question that does that to earn my downvote. I'm not sure if it fits any of our close reasons, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that without motivation, the question is **unclear**, and i also tend to downvote stuff like that.

It's unclear, because we can't be expected to know why you think a source might say that. It's not even too hard to make it an acceptable question: Just say: "I read here that xyz says abc. Where does xyz say that?"

Comment: "It's unclear, because we can't be expected to know why you think a source might say that." I don't know what is unclear about that. Motivation makes questions easier to answer correctly and helps encourage users to put time into answering it. It doesn't necessarily make a question more intelligible (depends on the specific q and the potential motivation).